# PACT .NET consumer test: flexible length array

Tags: c#, consumer, contract, pact, pact-net

I am using pactNet to test an API which should return an array of a flexible length.

If i call "myApi/items/" it should return a list of items where the consumer does not know the exact size of.
So the answer should look like this:

```
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "description": "foo"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "description": "foo2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "description": "foo3"
        }
    ]
```

or this:

```
    [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "description": "foo4"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "description": "foo2"
        }
    ]
```

How do I create the contract for this interaction?

In the [documentation](https://docs.pact.io/documentation/matching.html) is an example in Ruby, but I cannot find the equivalent in C#.

I am using pactNet version 2.1.1.

Edit: Here is an example how it should look like. What I want to know is how do I declare that the body should contain an array of items with a flexible length.

```
[Test]
    public void GetAllItems()
    {
        //Arrange
        _mockProviderService
            .Given("There are items")
            .UponReceiving("A GET request to retrieve the items")
            .With(new ProviderServiceRequest
            {
                Method = HttpVerb.Get,
                Path = "/items/",
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Accept", "application/json" }
                }
            })
            .WillRespondWith(new ProviderServiceResponse
            {
                Status = 200,
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
                },
                Body = // array of items with some attributes
                       // (somthing like: {"id": "2", "description": "foo"}) 
                       // with flexible length
            });

        var consumer = new ItemApiClient(_mockProviderServiceBaseUri);

        //Act
        var result = consumer.GetItems();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(true, result.Count > 0);

        _mockProviderService.VerifyInteractions();

        data.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the MinTypeMatcher.

The body part would look something like below:

```
Body = Match.MinType(new { id: "1", description: "foo" }, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exacly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For a nested array scenario like @SlimSjakie asked, just repeat Match.MinType at the property that has array. For example, the following Person object has Address property as an array.

```
Person = Match.MinType(new
{
    FirstName = Match.Type("string"),
    LastName = Match.Type("string"),
    Address = Match.MinType(new
    {
        Street = Match.Type("string"),
        Town = Match.Type("string"),
        State = Match.Type("string"),
        Postcode = Match.Type("string"),
        Country = Match.Type("string")
    }, 1)
}, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what if I want to Match the type of an object that has a property that is a list or array?

if you do a Match.Type(new myType()) and the number of elements in the array or list property is not exactly the same, the test will fail. You will see an error like this:

```
Description of differences
--------------------------------------
* Actual array is too long and should not contain a Hash at $.data.itinerary[2]
```